# How to set default handler method in controller in Spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring mvc application in which I have to display a list of locations. I have a controller method for location. Following is my controller method code:

```
@RequestMapping("/location")
public class LocationController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String showAllLocations(ModelMap modelMap) {
        logger.info("showAllLocations() begins:");
        try {
            List<LocationModel> locationList = locationService
                    .getAllLocations("");
            modelMap.addAttribute("locationlist", locationList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Error while getting locations: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "LocationHome";
    }
}
```

It works fine when I user following URL:

http://www.example.com:8080/myapp/location/home

But when I use http://www.example.com:8080/myapp/location, it shows error.

How can I view location list without using 'home', by following URL:

http://www.example.com:8080/myapp/location

Comment: have you tried adding `@RequestMapping(value = "")`

Comment: value can be an array. @RequestMapping(value = { "/home", "/" } )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public String doHome(ModelMap modelMap) {
   ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
public String doDefault(ModelMap modelMap) {
   ...
}
```

Make sure you put more specific request handler before less specific one.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
This can map you to a default handler.

Answer (score 0):

You have the request mapping for the `LocationController` here ,

```
            @RequestMapping("/location")
            public class LocationController {..}
```

So all the URL to be intercepted by this controller should have the pattern `/location` followed by the method request mapping as here ,

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
        public String showAllLocations(ModelMap modelMap) {..}
```

If you need to intercept the `request` for `http://www.example.com:8080/myapp/location` . Just remove the url mapping from the controller and assign it to the method.